# Seed Database in Entity Framework with a Database Generated Identity Column

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

How can I seed my database with a database generated ID column without creating new entries?  For example:

```
public class Stuff
{
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

and seed method:

```
 var project1Id = new Guid("8853EDF3-BA20-43F8-B8D6-06984116CF8C");
 context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id, new Project 
 {
      Id =  project1Id,
      Statuses = new List<Status> 
      { 
             new Status { Comments = "Comment 1", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now, Type = StatusType.Internal },
             new Status { Comments = "Comment 2", LastUpdated = DateTime.Now, Type = StatusType.Business }
       }
  });
```

The problem lies in that it ignores my specified GUID, and instead auto-generated a new one each time I run `update-database`.  I am using VS2012 and EF5.

Comment: Well, it ignores the supplied ids because you said `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. Do you want to supply the id manually in your `Seed` method but then later in the application have a database generated id? I'm not sure if I understand that correctly...

Comment: Slauma - yes, that is exactly what I want.  Or the other option would be that the AddOrUpdate method would know about previous adds to the database.

Comment: @Slauma i had a feeling that identity stuff gets turned on or reset after seeding as you often explicitly want a specific ID for seed data but perhaps I am mistaken? (ive never tested this just assumed but afaik it hasnt bitten me before)